# Same behaviour Scala Spark Sample and SampleBy

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, sampling

I'm trying to perform stratified sampling in a Spark Dataframe, but the behaviour of the sampleBy function is (oddly) similar to sample.

Spark version 3.0.1

```
import spark.implicits._

val data = Seq( ("Java", 20000), ("Java", 10000), ("Java", 3000),  ("Java", 17000),
                ("Python", 100000), ("Python", 20000),
                ("Scala", 3000), ("Scala", 4000), ("Scala", 1000), ("Scala", 43000), ("Scala", 2000), ("Scala", 9000)).toDF("Language", "Price")
val sample_size = 0.5
val seed = 762387
val stratify = "Language"

val subsample = data.sample(withReplacement=false, fraction=sample_size, seed=seed)

subsample.show()

val fractions = data.select(stratify).distinct().as[String].collect().map((_, sample_size)).toMap
println(fractions.mkString("\n")
val stratified_subsample = data.stat.sampleBy(stratify, fractions=fractions, seed=seed)

stratified_subsample.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+
|Language| Price|
+--------+------+
|    Java|  3000|
|  Python|100000|
|  Python| 20000|
|   Scala|  3000|
|   Scala| 43000|
|   Scala|  2000|
|   Scala|  9000|
+--------+------+

Scala -> 0.5
Python -> 0.5
Java -> 0.5

+--------+------+
|Language| Price|
+--------+------+
|    Java|  3000|
|  Python|100000|
|  Python| 20000|
|   Scala|  3000|
|   Scala| 43000|
|   Scala|  2000|
|   Scala|  9000|
+--------+------+
```

Output with another seed (6354345):

```
+--------+------+
|Language| Price|
+--------+------+
|    Java| 10000|
|    Java| 17000|
|  Python|100000|
|   Scala|  3000|
|   Scala|  4000|
|   Scala|  1000|
|   Scala| 43000|
|   Scala|  2000|
|   Scala|  9000|
+--------+------+

Scala -> 0.5
Python -> 0.5
Java -> 0.5

+--------+------+
|Language| Price|
+--------+------+
|    Java| 10000|
|    Java| 17000|
|  Python|100000|
|   Scala|  3000|
|   Scala|  4000|
|   Scala|  1000|
|   Scala| 43000|
|   Scala|  2000|
|   Scala|  9000|
+--------+------+
```

I've tried with different DataFrames, different seeds and both dataframes are always equal. I have always the same behaviour, the sample is not stratified at all. I know sampleBy is not exact, but having the same behaviour doesn't seem ok. Is something wrong in my snippet?

Comment: Thanks, I have added another example. I have edited the comment because with "nothing changes" I meant "the behaviour keeps being the same between the two functions".

Answer (score -1):

When you use "seed" you will get the same sample. If you fill it as 0 then you will get a different sample every time you run it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29856160)